# Determining set of events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have answered the following:

A intersect B is the event that at most odd integer is selected (or the empty set) (e.g. could have $A = \{1,3,4\}$ and $B = \{3,4,6\}$ and we get $A \cap B = \{3,4\}$ but we can never get more than one odd integer)

$B \backslash A = $ the event that at most one odd integer is selected

Two points I need help with:

- Is $A \cap B$ is the same as $B \backslash A$?
- I am really struggling to see $ A \backslash B$, at least how to describe it in one sentence

Comment: Your interpretation of $A \cap B$ is mostly correct.  You are correct that in $A \cap B$ we can never get more than one odd integer.  But it's also true that we can never get fewer than one odd integer.  In other words, $A \cap B$ will always have exactly one odd integer.  The answers below describe this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your descriptions of the intersection and the difference are incorrect.  When intersecting two events, you should think "$A\cap B$ is the event that both $A$ and $B$ occur."  In this case, you select at least one odd number (event $A$), and at most one odd number (event $B$).  This means that you have selected exactly one odd number, thus
$$ A\cap B : \text{exactly one odd number is selected}.$$

For the difference, think "$A\setminus B$ is the event that $A$ happens, but not $B$."  In this case, you select at least one odd number (event $A$), but not 0 or 1 odd numbers (the event "not $B$").  Thus
$$ A \setminus B : \text{at least two odd numbers are selected}.$$

Finally, $B\setminus A$ is the event that you select at most one odd number (event $B$), but fewer than 1 odd numbers (the event "not $A$").  Hence
$$ B \setminus A : \text{no odd numbers are selected}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, $B \setminus A = B \cap \overline{A}$ and $B \cap A$ are not the same (however, this can hold when $B = \varnothing$). In this case, $A \setminus B$ corresponds to the event where $A$ holds but $B$ does not. Try thinking about how to describe the event $\overline{B}$ and then get an expression for $A \setminus B = A \cap \overline{B}$.

I think here you're confusing outcomes with events. $A$ and $B$ are both events, i.e. sets of outcomes. So the intersection of these events should be sets of outcomes as well (each of which can be represented as triples of numbers selected).